# Using Bash shell, I am attempting to print only the lines not divisible by 3 from an input file

Tags: bash

I am attempting to print only the lines that are not divisible by 3 from an input file. The issue is that when I try to feed an input file into my shell script using the command  `bash script.sh < input.txt` I get `"line 7: [: too many arguments"`, many times. How can I go about printing only lines that are not divisible by 3 from the input file?

```
line_number=1;

while read line
do
  if [ $line_number % 3 -ne 0 ];
  then
     echo "$line"
  fi
  let "line_number += 1"
done
```

the input file contains the following:
named: input.txt

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
```

Comment: `awk '!(NR%3==0)' file`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Or `awk 'NR % 3' file`.

Comment: Alternatively, with GNU sed: `sed '3~3d' file`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, but you cannot do arithmetic in `[ ... ]`, instead you need to use the POSIX arithmetic syntax of `(( ... ))` and within `(( ... ))` you do not need to prefix the variable name with `'$'` as a dereference.

In your case you can do:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

[ -z "$1" ] && {    ## validate one argument give for filename
    printf "error: filename required.\n" >&2
    exit 1
}

[ -s "$1" ] || {    ## validate file non-empty and readable
    printf "error: file '%s' empty or not readable.\n" "$1" >&2
    exit 1
}

line_number=1       ## initialize line number

## loop reading each line (protect agains non-POSIX eof)
while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]
do
    if (( line_number % 3 != 0 ))   ## check modulo of line number
    then
        echo "$line"
    fi
    ((line_number++))               ## increment line number
done < "$1"
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your example input in `file`

```
$ example.sh file
a
b
d
e
g
h
j
k
m
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.